# Which part of this C++ program accesses memory is not belonging to me?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
unsigned char* readBMP(char* filename) {
    int i;
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    unsigned char info[54];
    fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];

    int size = 3 * width * height;
    unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i += 3) {
            unsigned char tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[i+2];
            data[i+2] = tmp;
    }

    return data;
}

int main() {
    char* filename = "image.bmp";
    unsigned char* originalImageData = readBMP(filename);
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(originalImageData);i++) {
        cout << originalImageData[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When running the program it results in:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

By the way, is there a way to locate this kind of runtime error without using some IDE? (This is a `CMake` project, so I don't think `gcc -g` and `gdb` would work.)

Comment: `sizeof(originalImageData)` -- This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Try a debugger or just adding some prints to see how far it gets before crashing. The fact you don't check the `fopen` result is scary...

Comment: This project is a CMake project, so actually I compiled it using cmake and make

Comment: `int width = *(int*)&info[18];` breaks strict aliaising rule (and doesn't handle aliasing neither anyway). And so it is pedantically UB.

Comment: Most debuggers can be used in command line...

Comment: Maybe you should be focused on *why* you are getting segmentation faults.  The problems with the code are elementary issues (such as misuse/misunderstanding of `sizeof`, dangerous C-style casting, etc.).

Comment: `char* filename = "image.bmp";` is not a valid line in C++. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, it's this line:

```
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header
```

If the `fopen` fails, which you don't check, `f` will be `NULL`. And `NULL` definitely doesn't point to memory that belongs to you.

You have two other issues as well:

```
int width = *(int*)&info[18];
int height = *(int*)&info[22];
```

This won't work. Nobody stored an `int` there, so you can't read one. It can crash on some architectures and the results will depend on non-portable details such as `sizeof(int)`. Do the conversions correctly.

Also:

```
unsigned char* originalImageData = readBMP(filename);
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(originalImageData);i++) {
    cout << originalImageData[i];
}
```

Since `originalImageData` is a pointer, `sizeof(originalImageData)` is the size of that pointer. That's not what you want. Why do you care how big the pointer is?

Answer (score 0):

First things first: This is **not** a C++ program. Throwing a plain C program to a C++ compiler does not make it C++.

Your second question: Segfaults can be located by mainly two techniques:

- a debugger. GDB if you are on gcc/clang, this is a commandline tool.
- put `cout` statements throughout your code, so you see how far it runs before the segfault. It's a bit tedious - but it works.

Your initial question is difficult to answer without running it through a compiler/debugger. (Hint: it's not the purpose of stackoverflow to have other users debug your code)

There are a few obvious issues with the code where you take assumptions like the file length or the existence of an integer at a specific place (`info[18]`). What if that integer reads not the correct value? You will have vastly wrong values for `data` and the size of your image. @[DavidSchwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) has already provided quite a good answer.

There is a saying in C++:

> when you have `new` in your code, you might have a memory leak - when you have `delete` in your code **you know** that you have a memory leak.